# Gson how to avoid Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON to parse JSON data into Java and I am running into the error that is stated in the title. I am working with an API that returns the following JSON data :

```
{
  "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
  "NUM_RECORDS": "5",
  "MESSAGE": "5 records found",
  "AVAILABILITY_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP": "2015-05-03T13:59:08.541-07:00",
  "AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP": "2015-05-03T13:59:08.490-07:00",
  "AVL": [
    {
      "TYPE": "ON",
      "BFID": "205052",
      "NAME": "5th St (500-598)",
      "RATES": {
        "RS": [
          {
            "BEG": "12:00 AM",
            "END": "12:00 PM",
            "RATE": "0",
            "RQ": "No charge"
          },
          {
            "BEG": "12:00 PM",
            "END": "6:00 PM",
            "RATE": "5",
            "RQ": "Per hour"
          },
          {
            "BEG": "6:00 PM",
            "END": "12:00 AM",
            "RATE": "0",
            "RQ": "No charge"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PTS": "2",
      "LOC": "-122.4002212834,37.7776161738,-122.3989619795,37.7766113458"
    },
    {
      "TYPE": "ON",
      "BFID": "205042",
      "NAME": "5th St (450-498)",
      "RATES": {
        "RS": {
          "BEG": "12:00 AM",
          "END": "12:00 AM",
          "RATE": "0",
          "RQ": "No charge"
        }
      },
      "PTS": "2",
      "LOC": "-122.4015027158,37.7786330718,-122.4005149869,37.7778485214"
    },
  ]
}
```

I can see where the problem occurs, the `RS` field can either contain an array of objects (let's call this object `RInfo`) or in some cases it will only contain one of that `RInfo` object that is not contained in an array. I think that the error occurs because GSON is looking for an array but found an object. I am unable to change the structure of the JSON file because it was provided by an API.

I am able to parse the information successfully as long as `RS` is an array of `RInfo` objects but in some cases `RS` contains only one `RInfo` object so this error occurs.

Is there a way to handle this in GSON?

***Update**

I have tried a solution that was linked earlier. Here is what I have from that solution:

```
class RSDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RateInfo[]> {

    @Override
    public RateInfo[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException
    {


        if (json instanceof JsonArray) {
            System.out.println("fromJson in RSD:" + new Gson().fromJson(json, RateInfo[].class));
            return new Gson().fromJson(json, RateInfo[].class);
        }
        RateInfo rI = context.deserialize(json, RateInfo.class);

        return new RateInfo[] { rI };
    }

}
```

I have also created a new GsonBuilder as follows

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(RateInfo[].class, new RSDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

It doesn't seem like the custom deserializer is ever used because the print statement was never printed out in the console. After that I have tried to deserilize the json using `MyOBJ info = gson.fromJson(json, MyOBJ.class);` this line gives me the Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT exception.

Comment: I have tried that solution but couldn't get it to work. Does custom deserialization work on more complicated Json files such as the one I am working with?

Comment: Yes, works fine with more complex JSONs. Any error with your custom solution?

Comment: I have updated my initial post with what I have tried. It doesn't seem like the custom deserializer is being used.

Comment: Jackson has [a built in feature](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) to support this, I'm surprised Gson doesn't have the same.

Comment: I've tried your deserializer and it works well for me. You can check this simple gist: https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/3bdae1589b320b6405e1

Comment: @AlexisC. For some reason it works with `Array` but doesn't work with `ArrayList`. I'm not really sure why...

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel It works also fine for me when I deserialize it into an `ArrayList`. Please give me a pastebin of the gist I published with your modifications when you try to serialize it into a `List`.

Comment: @AlexisC. Here is the pastebin of the code I am trying to run http://pastebin.com/F3Yss5Qm . It gives an `IllegalStateException` saying Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 274 path $.AVL[0].RATES.RS.

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel Not surprising it doesn't work if you don't update the deserializer to return an `ArrayList<RateInfo>`... and same when you register it in your `GsonBuilder`.

Comment: @AlexisC. I thought that the type in the `< >` was the type GSON searches for in the Json data? I am not exactly sure how I would update the deserializaer to return an `ArrayList<RateInfo>`. Would I just change `RateInfo[]` to `ArrayList<RateInfo>`?

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel Yes. And since generics are erased at runtime, you'd need to use a `TypeToken` when calling `fromJson` and registering your adapter: `new TypeToken<ArrayList<RateInfo>>(){}.getType()`

Comment: @AlexisC. Could you give me an example using `TypeToken`? I am not really sure I am understanding you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the deserializer to tell that you want to return a `List<RateInfo>`:

```
class RSDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<RateInfo>> {
    @Override
    public List<RateInfo> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json instanceof JsonArray) {
            return Arrays.asList(context.deserialize(json, RateInfo[].class));
        }
        return Collections.singletonList(context.deserialize(json, RateInfo.class));
    }
}
```

and you need to also tell to the parser that this is the type you want to deserialize too when registering this adapter:

```
Type t = new TypeToken<List<RateInfo>>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(t, new RSDeserializer()).create();
```

A full working example can be found in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/3bdae1589b320b6405e1).